# How can I make pdf with snippet in reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am new in programming and have got weak background to deal with snippet.
My problem is that I have no idea about how to use the snippet included in the ReportLab user guide

https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

I just follow by this protocol 
All I have done is the code in section 2.1 - 2.6 
But in section 2.7, I have no idea how to use function (def...) to create pdf

My question is:

(1) What is the basic background that I should know?
(2) Could you please give me some example code that show how to deal with this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial.  The snippet below should create a file "hello.pdf" in the same directory as your python script.

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
c.drawString(100,750,"Welcome to Reportlab!")
c.save()
```

Comment: That's great I am glad it helped.  If you like please accept my answer.  It helps my profile.  Thanks